# PHP generate list with variation from multidimensional array

Tags: php, random, multidimensional-array

I am really stuck on trying to create php queries to generate report from multidimensional array.

1. Generate random names based on group number selected
2. Print 3 random names first selected group AND print 2 random names other selected group

Data Example:

```
 $group1 = [
            'Type 1' = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'Name 4']
            'Type 2' = ['Name 5', 'Name 6', 'Name 7', 'Name 8']
            'Type 3' = ['Name 9', 'Name 10', 'Name 11', 'Name 12']
             ]

$group2 = [
            'Type 1' = ['Name 13', 'Name 14', 'Name 15', 'Name 16']
            'Type 2' = ['Name 17', 'Name 18', 'Name 19', 'Name 20']
            'Type 3' = ['Name 21', 'Name 22', 'Name 23', 'Name 24']
             ]

 $group3 = [
            'Type 1' = ['Name 25', 'Name 26', 'Name 27', 'Name 28']
            'Type 2' = ['Name 29', 'Name 30', 'Name 31', 'Name 32']
            'Type 3' = ['Name 33', 'Name 34', 'Name 35', 'Name 36']
             ]
…
```

PHP output Example :

```
Group Selected:  1 AND 3

Type 1: Name 1, Name 3, Name 2, Name 26, Name 28
Type 2: Name 6, Name 5, Name 7, Name 30, Name 31
Type 3: Name 9, Name 10, Name 11, Name 35, Name 36
```

I really appreciated your response.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: I did used array_rand() to generate random 2 or 3 names, and I used IF ELSE function to print selected group...however, it was bad programming... example   $rand_group_1_2names = array_rand($group1, 2); $rand_group_1_3names = array_rand($group1, 3);

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understood

```
$group1 = array(
            'Type 1' => array('Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'Name 4'),
            'Type 2' => array('Name 5', 'Name 6', 'Name 7', 'Name 8'),
            'Type 3' => array('Name 9', 'Name 10', 'Name 11', 'Name 12')
             );

$group2 = array(
            'Type 1' => array('Name 13', 'Name 14', 'Name 15', 'Name 16'),
            'Type 2' => array('Name 17', 'Name 18', 'Name 19', 'Name 20'),
            'Type 3' => array('Name 21', 'Name 22', 'Name 23', 'Name 24')
             );

$group3 = array(
            'Type 1' => array('Name 25', 'Name 26', 'Name 27', 'Name 28'),
            'Type 2' => array('Name 29', 'Name 30', 'Name 31', 'Name 32'),
            'Type 3' => array('Name 33', 'Name 34', 'Name 35', 'Name 36')
             );
// Array of selected groups          
$selected_groups = array(1,3);
// Making names of selected group arrays
print_r(make_array(${'group'.$selected_groups[0]}, ${'group'.$selected_groups[1]}));

function make_array($ar1, $ar2) {
// 'Type 1', 'Type 2', 'Type 3' 
    foreach (array_keys($ar1) as $key)
// Collect in $res what we want - 3 names from 1st array and 2 from 2nd
        $res[$key] = array_merge(array_rand(array_flip($ar1[$key]), 3), array_rand(array_flip($ar2[$key]), 2));
    return $res;
}
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/351605)

Comment: Thanks **splash58** it helped me creating the function to generate report

Answer (score 0):

```
$group1 = array(
            'Type 1' => array('Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'Name 4'),
            'Type 2' => array('Name 5', 'Name 6', 'Name 7', 'Name 8'),
            'Type 3' => array('Name 9', 'Name 10', 'Name 11', 'Name 12')
             );

$group2 = array(
            'Type 1' => array('Name 13', 'Name 14', 'Name 15', 'Name 16'),
            'Type 2' => array('Name 17', 'Name 18', 'Name 19', 'Name 20'),
            'Type 3' => array('Name 21', 'Name 22', 'Name 23', 'Name 24')
             );

$group3 = array(
            'Type 1' => array('Name 25', 'Name 26', 'Name 27', 'Name 28'),
            'Type 2' => array('Name 29', 'Name 30', 'Name 31', 'Name 32'),
            'Type 3' => array('Name 33', 'Name 34', 'Name 35', 'Name 36')
             );

$selected = array(1,3);

foreach (array(1,2,3) as $idx) {
    $sel1 = ${'group' . reset($selected)}['Type ' . $idx];
    $sel2 = ${'group' . end($selected)}['Type ' . $idx];
    $found1 = array_intersect_key($sel1, array_flip(array_rand($sel1, 3)));
    $found2 = array_intersect_key($sel2, array_flip(array_rand($sel2, 2)));
    echo "Type $idx: " . implode (", ", $found1) . ', ' .  implode (",", $found2);
    echo "<br>";
}
```